# How do I use QSCC to query the block information in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have been trying to get block information and other block level queries using QSCC. Can someone please help me with the steps/ or direct me to a helpful resource. So far I haven't come across any helpful information apart from the docs [system-chaincode](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/systemchaincode.html)

Comment: Are you using any sdk or trying out through peer commands?

Comment: java sdk and also trying with peer commands as well. So far I tried with the peer chaincode query command on qscc chaincode but it returns some gibberish results.

Comment: Ok. And which sdk method are you using to get the block information?

Comment: I havent found any sdk method for that unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried running queryBlockByNumber or queryBlockByTransactionID or queryBlockByHash from java-sdk?

Comment: I have tried those from cli, but it returns gibberish results. Will try from sdk as well.